# How to make any Windows application unresponsive?

Tags: windows

I have a rather unusual dilemma:

Can you share a few methods for causing any Windows desktop application to stop working, as fast as possible?

I want to be able to open any application and so something so that it freezes and Windows marks it as "Not Responding". One idea that I tried is to force an application to open an unsupported file format. For example, I forced Notepad to open an .exe file and it did the trick.

How about other ideas?

Comment: May I ask why??

Comment: You didn't make notepad stop working by opening an .EXE file. In fact the notepad is rather inefficient if used to open a file > 20MB. But if you wait long enough (>15 Minutes) it will eventually show character salads from the .EXE and become resposive again.

Comment: I am working on some educational materials where I need to demo how to deal with unresponsive applications of all kinds. Therefore I need to crash several applications and then do the necessary screenshots + explaining.

Comment: Is your objective just to halt the program, like grawity's solution, or to actually generate the "not responding" message for your demo?

Comment: @fixer1234: It's the same thing. The "Not responding" message appears precisely because the program has halted.

Comment: @grawity - If you manually halt a program, you don't get a "not responding" message.

Comment: I must get the Not Responding message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) or [ProcExp](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx), right-click the process name, and select "Suspend". From the command line you can use [PsSuspend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897540.aspx).

Alternatively, attach a debugger to the process (e.g. run `ntsd -p <processid>` for the "NT symbolic debugger").

As long as a process is suspended this way, it won't run any code, so it won't reply to window messages either, so the window manager will consider the application to be hung after a quick while.

Comment: Suspending the process will not accomplish what the OP wants. The application becomes suspended but Windows will not mark it as "not responding". The way I've accomplished this in the past has been to either do as the OP suggests, i.e. open a large file in notepad (if you want to get notepad's window to become unresponsive for a bit), or lock a resource the program will hang on, e.g. a mutex that the program tries to gain access to in a blocking fashion.